# Colour of render is desaturated after saving

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

My EEVEE renders look fine in the render window but when i save them they are desaturated. the only partial solution i have found is to uncheck the 'save as render' box but this seems to make the colours *too* saturated.i know that i could bump up the saturation beforehand but this would overexpose the image and cause less colour variation i think.its just very peculiar.... any help on how to rectify this frustrating issue would be much appreciated. thanks.

ive added a blend file as an example of how i have been working:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to set the color depth to 16 bits when saving?

Comment: yes have tried that, tried different image formats too, they all have the same desaturated look. could i just confirm that other people are not getting this issue?

Comment: Could you upload the model or part of it (with textures packed if have some)? Please use this link: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi, added a blend file with same textures and HDRI, settings etc.

Comment: I think the png is ok, but the result depends on the viewer you're using. Reloading it with Blender or Gimp seems to be ok, but Windows viewer ("photos") is darker.

Comment: i sent the file to a friend of mine and both outputs look the same on his computer (in the render viewer in blender and the saved PNG file) - so this means that for some reason things look more saturated within blender on my computer. this is a problem because it means its difficult to tweak colours to how i actually want them. i wonder what it could be?